# Продуктивное обучение

Tags: javascript, html, css

Начал изучать html/css, webref,htmlacademy, видосы в ютубе, вроде смотришь и все понимаешь, а когда наступает время практики - тупняк полнейший.
Позиционирование на теории - не сложно, как практика даже сделать что-либо сложно.
Тоже самое было, когда пробовал изучать JS.
Если, кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой - поделитесь опытом как выйти из тупика?

Answer (score 3):

Смысла просто смотреть, читать если при этом самому не пробовать - нет.

Я, когда изучаю новую технологию, сразу же пробую в коде. Каждый момент который изучаю сразу же применяю на примере, до полного понимания.

Если просто посмотреть или почитать, то информация находится на умственном, ментальном уровне, потом оттуда она легко улетучивается.

Если же ты это делаешь руками, то информация проходит через практику, в этом случае это уже не просто информация а реальный опыт + понимание что как работает, а опыт в отличие от теории не забывается. Точнее что бы он забылся нужно существенно больше времени.

Более того, просто опробовав каждый момент по отдельности этого тоже недостаточно, после для полного освоения необходимо ещё сделать полноценный, но возможно мини-тестовый проект по освоенной технологии.

Если при уже конкретной практике и пробах возникают трудности, в этом случае можно обращаться на StackOverflow за разъяснениями.

Comment: Дело в том, что, когда читал или смотрел, переписывал код, пробовал изменять значения и такой "опа, это делает так, а это по-другому" и думаешь - все вкурил.
А, когда нужно реализовать что-либо несложное, тупо не понимаешь, как это реализовать

Comment: @fokucnuk может быть попробовать с ещё более простого, с того что понятно, и усложнять поэтапно